# Cant solve issue with DNS regex search

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7, load-balancing

I am trying to build a regex that will pull (somewhat) all dns names out of a massive load balancing config. I am new to regex and it seems that my syntax for the regex is off and causing the error: invalid syntax. I have learned a lot of python recently but just got introduced to the magical world of regex a couple days ago, it is a power full animal if one can harness it. :D

The input looks like:

```
add lb vserver LB_TEST_EXT_treehouse.uncle.com SSL 10.212.17.100 443 
add lb vserver LB_TEST_INT_treehouse.uncle.com SSL 10.212.17.99 443 
add lb vserver REDIRECT_INT_tnucwcf.monkey.com HTTP 10.212.17.147 80 -
add lb vserver REDIRECT_EXT_tnucwcf.monkey.com HTTP 10.212.17.148 80 -
bind lb vserver LB_tnucleuswcf.oncologysupply.com 130-wbsvc-t-004
bind lb vserver SSL_INT_unucwcfSL.monkey.com 130-wbsvc-t-004
bind lb vserver SSL_EXT_unucwcfSL.moneky.com 130-wbsvc-t-004
bind lb vserver SSL_INT_unucrepSL.monkey.com 130-wbsvc-t-004
bind lb vserver SSL_EXT_unucrepSL.monkey.com 130-wbsvc-t-004
bind ssl vserver CS_INT_tnucwcf.monkey.com -eccCurveName P_256
bind ssl vserver CS_INT_league.oflegends.com -eccCurveName P_384
```

Here is my code snippet. All help is appreciated a head of time. Thank you for reading. It should see the url and then grab the whole string its apart of for every line as I can get rid of duplicates later.

```
import re

dns = []
filename = ('ns-config.back')
with open(filename + 'txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'(add lb vserver )(\S+)(([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))
([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?,line)':
        dns.append()
print(dns)
```

Comment: what do you want the regex to match...?

Comment: I would like it to match something along the lines of  barney.elmo.com or barney_elmo_com, bc the naming convention before was horrible. It does not have to be perfect bc I can go back and strip things like IP address if it grabs them as I noticed this regex does, but I noticed it doesnt miss urls. except for the ones that include the underscores.

Comment: please edit the question, showing what the input looks like, and **exactly** what you do and don't want the regex to match.

Comment: OK I updated with some example netscaler configs. They will always begin in index 2 and end at 3 if it helps

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, would it be more efficient to use index positions  to copy the whole string instead of using regex.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you want to match. Anything of the form X.Y.com or X_Y_com?

Comment: You're getting the syntax error because you forgot the close parenthesis on your `re.search()` statement.

Comment: Try to debug your regex at [Regex101](https://regex101.com)